# onDelet not updating list

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

im doing a litte app using what i'm learning from the 100daysofswiftui i have a navigation view where you can add and delet user an a navigation link to see more details.

in the detail view you can add address to the user and delete it but the delete its not working

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
@State private var showAddAddressView = false

 let user : User

 ...

 List {
  Section(header: Text("Address")) {
                                ForEach(self.user.addressArray, id: \.self){ address in
                                    AddressCard(address: address)
                                }.onDelete(perform: self.deleteItem)
                            }

                         }
                         .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                         .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)

...

 func deleteItem(at offsets: IndexSet) {

        for offset in offsets { 
            let address =  self.user.addressArray[offset] 

            self.moc.delete(address)
        }

        try? self.moc.save()

       }
```

this is not updating the list i have to get out of the detailView an back, then i can see the changes

Comment: SwiftUI does not know that you changed the property.
You have to make User an ObservableObject and use for user @Published property wrapper. Can you add the User class/struct?

Comment: @PaFi thanks that was the problem I just add the ObservableObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Volker88 and @PaFi 
I just add `@ObservedObject var user : User` to my object so that way swift knows something has change